# jquery tmpl in a closure

Tags: javascript, closures, jquery-templates

i am working on this little javascript library and following various suggestions i am wrapping my functionality in a closure for the various reasons (encapsulation of variables, hidding of code and so on). since I query a JSON webservice and display the results I also use the jquery tmpl engine.
I think I understand what closures are good for but I sure don't understand them in general. meaning I get totally lost between all those scope changes and whatnot. especially annoying is this exception I get. consider the following code (a simplified ugly version of the code in question, but it reproduces the problem)

```
// something would be the object that handles all the library functionality
var something = function(){

    // creating a local function that goes as a parameter into the Array.filter
    function isBar(data){
        return data.name === "bar";
    }

    // the template code
    var bla = "<h1>${name}<\h1><h2>${attribute.filter(isBar)[0].value}</h2>";

    // precompiling the the template
    $.template("test", bla);

    // and returning a function that should render the template with the provided data
    return {
        funny: function(){
            $.tmpl("test", [{"name":"Fo", "attribute":[{"name":"bar", "value":"how"}]},
                            {"name":"Foo", "attribute":[{"name":"fnord","value":"can"}]},
                            {"name":"Fooo", "attribute":[{"name":"bar","value":"this"}]},
                            {"name":"Foooo", "attribute":[{"name":"Bar", "value":"be"}]}
            ]);
        }
    }
}();
// calling the function
something.funny();
```

So when calling the `something.funny()` I would the following expect to happen: the function `funny`, being a closure gets called in its original context (e.g. the function `isBar` and the variable `bar` are defined). So when I call `$.tmpl` I hoped that `attribute.filter(isBar)` within the template would also be in this scope. but it isn't. I Chrome i get `ReferenceError: isBar is not defined`.
If someone would be so nice to show me the error of my ways I would be very happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*edit* oops I missed the "()".

OK, well the problem is that those references to the local variables in the closure are not really references to local variables - they're part of a **string**.  The template code has to parse that string, so when it does that the fact that there was a function called "isBar()" in the closure from where "$.tmpl()" was called really doesn't matter; jQuery can't access them because you just can't do that in JavaScript.

You *can*, however, pass in an "options" third parameter to "$.tmpl()" and provide extra stuff there. I'm not 100% sure how to do it as I've only played with the template plugin a little bit, but I'll try a jsfiddle when I have a chance.  I think that you'd basically do something like this:

```
    funny: function(){
        $.tmpl("test", [{"name":"Fo", "attribute":[{"name":"bar", "value":"how"}]},
                        {"name":"Foo", "attribute":[{"name":"fnord","value":"can"}]},
                        {"name":"Fooo", "attribute":[{"name":"bar","value":"this"}]},
                        {"name":"Foooo", "attribute":[{"name":"Bar", "value":"be"}]}
        ], { isBar: isBar });
    }
```

What I'm not sure of is whether you refer to that as "${isBar()}" or "${item.isBar()}" inside the template text.

Comment: yes thats it. I passed `{isBar: function(data){ return data.name === "bar";}` as the options parameter and its possible to refer to `${$item.isBar()}` within the template.  
thanks a lot!